# what is inequality join in mysql,how it works

Tags: mysql, sql

dealer table

```
ID | Product
------------
1   product1
1   product2
1   product3
1   product4
2   product1
2   product2
2   product3
3   product1
3   product2
3   product3
4   product1
4   product2
```

i want to find all id and its top 2 product

my try is

```
  select d1.id,d1.product,count(d1.product)
  from dealer d1 join
       dealer d2  
       on d1.id=d2.id
  where d1.product>=d2.product
  group by d1.id,d1.product
 having count(d1.product)<=2
```

my result is

```
id |product   |count(d1.product) 
----------------------------
1   product1    1
1   product2    2
2   product1    1
2   product2    2
3   product1    1
3   product2    2
4   product1    1
4   product2    2
```

google search says i got proper result due to inequality join but i want to know how inequality join working in this

Comment: on which basis you want to find top 2 ?

Comment: sir, value greater than or less than...suppose for id 1 products are 10 ,20 ,30,40 then i need 10,20  for id 2 products are 1,2,3 then i need products 1,2

Comment: `10 ,20 ,30,40` - where are you taking these digits?

Comment: 1 10
1 20
1 30
1 40
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 10
3 20
3 30
4 1
sir consider there are digits

Comment: consider product1=10 ,product2=10,product3=30,product4=40 in a table

Answer (score 13):

To understand how it works, just debug the query, step by step, but using a  smaller data set 
- for example only for rows with id = 1

```
select * from dealer;

| ID |  Product |
|----|----------|
|  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product2 |
|  1 | product3 |
|  1 | product4 |
```

The first evaluated part of the query is a join:

```
select *
from dealer d1 
join dealer d2  
on d1.id=d2.id AND d1.product>=d2.product
order by 1,2,3,4
```

How a join works ? 
It takes a first record from the left table (d1), then searches through the right table (d2) and pick from the right table all records that meet the join condition.
For the record with `product1` (d1 table) there is only one record from d2 table that meets the condition: `d1.product>=d2.product` - just `product1`.
So a partial resultset for 1st record from d1 is:

```
| ID |  Product | ID |  Product |
|----|----------|----|----------|
|  1 | product1 |  1 | product1 |
```

---

Then the query takes the next record from d1 - `product2`.
In this case there are 2 records that meet the join condition: `product1` and `product2`.
A partial resultset for 2nd record from d1 is:

```
| ID |  Product | ID |  Product |
|----|----------|----|----------|
|  1 | product2 |  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product2 |  1 | product2 |
```

---

Then the query takes the next record from d1 - `product3`.
In this case there are 3 records that meet the join condition: `product1`, `product2` and `product3`.
A partial resultset for 3rd record from d1 is:

```
| ID |  Product | ID |  Product |
|----|----------|----|----------|
|  1 | product3 |  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product3 |  1 | product2 |
|  1 | product3 |  1 | product3 |
```

---

Then the query takes the last record from d1 - `product4`.
In this case there are 4 records that meet the join condition: `product1`, `product2`, `product3` and `product4`.
A partial resultset for 4th record from d1 is:

```
| ID |  Product | ID |  Product |
|----|----------|----|----------|
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product2 |
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product3 |
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product4 |
```

---

And the whole resultset of the query is:

```
| ID |  Product | ID |  Product |
|----|----------|----|----------|
|  1 | product1 |  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product2 |  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product2 |  1 | product2 |
|  1 | product3 |  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product3 |  1 | product2 |
|  1 | product3 |  1 | product3 |
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product1 |
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product2 |
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product3 |
|  1 | product4 |  1 | product4 |
```

---

Next lets apply GROUP BY clause to the above resultset:

```
select d1.id,d1.product,count(d1.product)
from dealer d1 
join dealer d2  
on d1.id=d2.id AND d1.product>=d2.product
group by d1.id,d1.product;

| ID |  Product | count(d1.product) |
|----|----------|-------------------|
|  1 | product1 |                 1 |
|  1 | product2 |                 2 |
|  1 | product3 |                 3 |
|  1 | product4 |                 4 |
```

---

And the last step is to apply HAVING count(..) <= 2 to filter out from the above resultset all records with count > 2

```
select d1.id,d1.product,count(d1.product)
from dealer d1 
join dealer d2  
on d1.id=d2.id AND d1.product>=d2.product
group by d1.id,d1.product
having count(d1.product)<=2;

| ID |  Product | count(d1.product) |
|----|----------|-------------------|
|  1 | product1 |                 1 |
|  1 | product2 |                 2 |
```

---

I hope that now it's should be clear how it works.
All the above steps are included in this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4890/7

Comment: really thanks for your valuable time and efforts for me now i come to know